# Join in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, inner-join

I am working on a laravel project and I faced this small problem.

I have two tables `users` and `enrolls`, where a user can enroll in a course and then I store `user_id` and `course_id` in the `enroll` table.

Now I want to get users who enrolled in a specific course by `course_id`

```
$users =  SELECT * FROM users WHERE...
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have a Course table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little difficult without having the schema of the tables, but you can use the query builder in your model like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('enroll', 'users.id', '=', 'enroll.user_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a more *Laravel way*.

#### In User model

```
public function enrollments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'enrollment', 'user_id');
}
```

#### In Course class

```
public function enrollers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'enrollment', 'course_id');
}
```

Then you may just call `$user->enrollments()` and you'll get the courses a user has enrolled. Or vice versa from the course you may `$course->enrollers()` to get the users enrolled for that course.

Learn more about many to many relationships in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).